# Firebase Real Time Database Rule: allow in list uid to edit

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to allow `write` for a list of uid using, `auth.uid in ['ciAujxIqXQSdaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbb']`, but that's not the correct syntax, how can I do this?

```
{
     "rules": {
        "orders": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write":  "(data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) || auth.uid in ['ciAujxIqXQSdaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbb']",
            ".indexOn": ["negative_epoch"]
        },
        "users": {
                ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null",
        },
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `in` operation in the security rules language for the Realtime Database. So you'll have to do an or yourself:

```
"(data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) || auth.uid == 'ciAujxIqXQSdaaaaaaaaaa' || auth.uid == 'bbb'"
```

---

I usually find that after adding 2 or 3 UIDs this way, I create a new top-level list in the database to hold these UID:

```
"admins": {
  "ciAujxIqXQSdaaaaaaaaaa": true,
  "bbb": true
}
```

And then check against *that* list in my rules:

```
"(data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
```